# String character maximum in Visual studio 2013?

Tags: string, visual-studio-2013, max

So I just upgraded from 2010 to 2013 and there is a part of my code that isn't working anymore and it's looking like it's because there are too many characters in the string.

The string I am trying to pass has a length of 120,000 but I'm pretty sure the maximum is supposed to be 1,073,741,823

If i leave it all one string the object is never created at run time - not meaning that the string = nothing but that the string is never created in the first place.

If I break the string up into two equal parts manually, both strings are created and are recognized.

However, if I try to create another string out of both parts, the new string = nothing.

I never had a problem with this is 2010 and I don't see any information about it anywhere on the internet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Is your project configured to use the same `targetFramework` in both IDEs? Have you tried compiling using MSBuild from the command line? I would be very surprised if this has anything to do with the IDE...

Comment: My target framework is still 4.0 and when its set to one long string, the application wont compile because everything that references the string returns an error.

Comment: Can you reproduce the compilation errors with another, smaller project? Maybe a "hello world" console app that also declares and references this long string variable? If so, it would greatly increase your chances of getting help here; if we can't reproduce the error, we can't help you determine it's cause.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: First Ill give you a link to the string I am trying to use. http://radb.net/query/ and then use the query !gAS15169 ... You will get a whole big list of IP addresses, that's the string... Secondly I opened up a brand new project in 2013 and created a string.... Here is the result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B61WKr1o6pT7QklZNzlON2dfV3M/edit?usp=sharing ... As you can see the long string isn't recognized as a string while the short one is (you can infer from the colors and the fact that in the combined string, LongString is underlined saying that it isnt pointing to an object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less of an answer... more of a confirmation that crazy stuff is happening on your machine.

I got a `longString` by using the "!gAS15169" query on http://radb.net/query/.

I tried initializing the `longString` variable in a brand new C# project in VS2013 and it seemed to build and run just fine.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string longString = "66.249.64.0/20 ***";
        string greeting = "Hello World!";
        Console.WriteLine(greeting + " " + longString);
        Console.WriteLine("longString.Length = " + longString.Length);
    }
}
```

*** I couldn't include the entire string in this answer because SO has a limit of 30K characters in a post.

The output of the `Length` line is:

`longString.Length = 74363`

This isn't as long as you described in the question though, you said you had a `string` that was 10K characters. Either way, it shouldn't matter because [the maximum length for a `string` in .NET (VB or C#) is just over 2 billion characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx).

Also, I am running this on a 64bit PC and the C# project was set to build for "Any CPU".

I don't know why it isn't working for you but it should.

Comment: I hate it when Im the only one... Yeah I am running a 7 machine with x64 and the build is set to "any cpu"

Comment: Ok I found the error. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8tbya99.aspx .... but how do I fix it?

Comment: It seems to only be an issue as part of a VB source file. I would suggest that you place the data into a separate `.txt` file and then [read the data into a `string` variable in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a77w6kkx.aspx). This should overcome the VS/VB line-length limitation.

Comment: Going through some of my old questions and I am going to give you this for the effort. I appreciate the help.